# Cloudflare doesnt load my 404 error

Tags: error-templates, cloudflare

I have a site whose dns runs thru cloudflare.
My staging site shows our 404 error template fine but Cloudflare doesnt seem to process ti and just shows Crafts system template not found.
Anyone come across this?

Comment: just to make sure, when you get 404 page, you not in login state right?

Comment: Yes I am - tested in chrome incognito and it loads. Logged out of backend and template loads.....so this looks like the answer.